# NestJS: Cannot read property "'createObjectLiteralExpression'" of undefined

Tags: nestjs

After upgrade to NestJS 8, I got this when run `npm run start:dev`

```
Error Cannot read property "'createObjectLiteralExpression'" of undefined
```

Any idea what went wrong?

```
[System Information]
OS Version     : Linux 5.4
NodeJS Version : v12.19.0
NPM Version    : 6.14.8 

[Nest CLI]
Nest CLI Version : 8.1.1 

[Nest Platform Information]
platform-socket.io version : 8.0.6
platform-express version   : 8.0.6
microservices version      : 8.0.6
websockets version         : 8.0.6
schematics version         : 8.0.2
passport version           : 8.0.1
schedule version           : 1.0.1
swagger version            : 5.0.9
typeorm version            : 8.0.2
testing version            : 8.0.6
common version             : 8.0.6
config version             : 1.0.1
core version               : 8.0.6
jwt version                : 8.0.0
cli version                : 8.1.1
```

Answer (score 8):

I found the issue myself. Took me hours. `TypeScript` need to upgrade to v4+.

This is v4+ feature. Even though I read the [NestJS V8 blog](https://trilon.io/blog/announcing-nestjs-8-whats-new) carefully, still I missed it.